# How to convert WMTS to WMS?

Tags: arcgis-10.0, wms, wmts, autocad-map

I have a WMTS service which I want to use for my work.

The problem is that I can't use it with Autocad Map because it consumes only WMS, or ArcGIS 10, because ArcGIS 10.1 and above uses WMTS.

Is there any possibilities to convert it on the fly in a WMS?

Comment: Have you found a different answer for this? I would loved to be proved wrong, but an answer, even if it isn't to your liking, is still an answer.

Comment: No i haven't, im hoping only if autodesk will implement WMTS on its products. Cause as i see if you use WMS aerial data from different sources it is very far away regarding bing maps live geomap performance which is free on autodesk products.

Comment: How will that help? You can't convert wmts to wms, they are two different things.

Comment: I'm not trying to convert anymore, i m hopping to be able to use WMTS on future in autodesk products. For now, nothing.

Comment: OK. Well, in general, if someone has taken time to answer a question, correctly, it is considered polite to accept it :D. Not only will you gain reputation for accepting, but it is good for the site, as it improves the ratio of answered to unanswered questions. You have asked 11 questions, all with reasonable answers, and accepted none of them. Please reconsider this.

Answer (score 2):

No, or at least not without significant server-side hacking. In a WMTS the zoom levels are fixed before hand, and defined in WMTSCapabilities.xml. Each tile is a unique, pre-rendered resource, matching a pattern of zoomlevel/x/y, with an exact, pre-defined pixel size, usually 256 x 256. In WMS, in contrast, there is neither a pre-defined zoom level, nor a pre-defined pixel size, both of these being defined/derived via the BBOX and width/height parameters.

So, in short, they are totally different beasts. In theory, if you were prepared to have your WMS use fixed zoom levels, equal to those of your WMTS, then you could write something that would chop out the appropriate parts of WMTS tiles for any given request and mosaic them together. But, frankly, this strikes me as more work than setting up a WMS in the first place.

In my experience, at least as of ArcGIS 10.2, their implementation of WMTS was a bit flaky -- I have an outstanding bug filed with ESRI for non-rendering of 1:500 zoom level WMTS, which is outside of the zoom levels as established for Google Maps, but by no means excluded as a possibility by the OGC standard's document. ArcGIS also has a tendency to rescale WMTS tiles, to fit the current zoom level, rather than adjusting the ArcGIS zoom level to the requested WMTS zoom level, leading to image degradation and very slow rendering speeds (and completely missing the point of WMTS).

My personal view, from years of painful experience as a provider of both WMS and WMTS, is that WMTS really only works cleanly in a web environment, where there is a clearer mapping between a unique tile resource on a server and a rendered div on a page, and the notion of (geographic) scale, at least as it exists in a desktop GIS, disappears.

Answer (score 2):

You might want to checkout MapProxy. It can read tiles as a source and output WMS. The caveat here is that this is a lot easier for imagery. If you are looking to do this with vector data and labels it can still work but results will be limited.
MapProxy will be able to render intermediate layers because it will sub-sample higher resolution tile layer to do so.